# jasper report not working after installing my application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i am using jasper reports to display a number of reports. the problem is, after installing my application to some user computer.... all the reports display but one. i have tried different methods that work for all my reports but one. it displays no errors but just does not open anything.
processing stops at 
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, conn);

Comment: Please post your error stack trace..

Comment: no stack trace... just silently stops... the report works fine on my computer... on a different computer it does not.

Comment: can the fonts be the problem? must the fonts i use on my reports be installed on the user computer.... if a font isnt found?... is there supposed to be an error informing me that the font wasn't found?